# Sidebar button (div) not clickable when not next to an image (using jquery and bootstrap4)

Tags: jquery, html, image, button

So I'm trying to get a nice sidebar going, and I want it to be expandable / retractable when clicking a button right besides it, kind of like the bitbucket menu. However, when I try this, my div that acts as a button is only clickable next to my banner image but nowhere else. I have no idea what is causing this.
Any ideas?

Also when I remove the image, the whole div becomes unclickable.

Here's my code:
(needs local bootstrap4, popperjs and jquery)

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/webpage.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!--Sidebar-->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-toggle"></div>
        <!--Page content-->
        <img id="banner" class="img-fluid" src="images/DNA-strand.png" alt="banner"/>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Sidebar Layouts are ok</h1>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                        <p>I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.
                        I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.I love apple pie.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="js/popperjs/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--Menu toggle script-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#wrapper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

webpage.css:

```
/** { padding: 0; margin: 0; }*/
/*html, body, .full-height {*/
    /*min-height: 100vh !important;*/
    /*height: 100vh !important;*/
/*}*/

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}

/* Banner image */
#banner {
    object-fit: none; /* Do not scale the image */
    object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
    min-height: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Sidebar */
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    flex: 1;
    width: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: #2C3E50;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* sidebar button */
#menu-toggle {
    background: #395168;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Main content */
#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    flex: 1;
}

/* Change the width of the sidebar to display it */
#wrapper.menuDisplayed #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

/* Fix page content to not be overlapped by menu */

#wrapper.menuDisplayed #page-content-wrapper {
    padding-left: 270px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Fix page banner to not be overlapped by menu */

#wrapper.menuDisplayed #banner {
    padding-left: 270px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Fix menu button to not be overlapped by menu */

#wrapper.menuDisplayed #menu-toggle {
    padding-left: 270px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Sidebar styling */
.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddd;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    background: #16A085;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this has to do with z-index. My sidebar was overlapping the button div.

I solved the problem.